# Jquery solution like on played.to

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

How can I achieve such site behaviour like on http://www.played.to? I mean when you scroll a function automatically jump to next header with nice smooth transition. Is there any solution avaiable to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching through the page code I found a solution, here it is:

http://www.thepetedesign.com/demos/onepage_scroll_demo.html

Hope You will find it usefull.